# Sort through an array of objects and push objects with the same key/value pair to a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, javascript-objects

I need to sort through an array of objects and push objects with the same key/value pair to a new array.

The objects I'm sorting through are football players. I have all players in an array of objects and want to push each position into their own array.

Ex. each object has a key of "position" so any object with the value of "QB" for the key "position" should be pushed into a new array "Quarterbacks".

Here's the code so far — it's in Angular so I first save all the players to a variable "Roster" and from there need to separate players by position into separate arrays that hold all players for that position.

```js
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('PlayersCtrl', function (
    $scope,
    Player
  ) {
    // $scope.players = Player.getList().$object;
    var Roster = Player.getList().$object;

    console.log(Roster);
    
});
```

Although i'm interested in learning how to do this all in one function that pushes all positions into their own array, i'd also like to figure out how to do it for one position. Like how to push all the quarterbacks from the Roster into a new array of just quarterbacks.

Comment: How about giving some demo data?

Comment: @Icepickle let me know if this helps...

the Roster object is an array of 58 objects, each one a player. each player object has three key/value pairs — position, name, and salary.

I want to identify each player by their position, and if the position is QB, push each of those players (the full object) into a new array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are defining a separate array for each you could use a switch statement.

```
var roster  = [
  {player: "Ben", position: "qb", salary: 1000},
  {player: "Brown", position: "wr", salary: 1200},
  {player: "Landry", position: "qb", salary: 800}
];

var qbArray = [];
var wrArray = [];

function parseIntoArrayByPosition() {
  for (var i = 0; i < roster.length; i++) {
    var position = roster[i].position;

    switch (position) {
      case "qb":
        qbArray.push(roster[i]);
        break;
      case "wr":
        wrArray.push(roster[i]);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: got it to return an empty array, not sure why I can't get any data back from any of these answers...

Comment: @Krang did you ensure that "roster" has the data and that it is formatted as you are expecting?

Comment: I think this is not the correct answer, we can have a lot of records with multiple values in key position, we can create multiple array for each of them, rather we should be able to create one array with key position, under which the respective objects should be added.

Comment: @SamiUllah That is not what the Author had asked for they said, "I have all players in an array of objects and want to push each position into their own array."

Answer (score 0):

```
var positions = {};

for(var i = 0; i < Roster.length; i++) {
    var position = Roster[i].position;
    positions[position] = positions[position] || [];
    positions[position].push(Roster[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could go through it with a forEach loop, and then assign your player based on a map of positions.

In my example (excuse my football knowledge), I run through an the `arrayOfObject` using the forEach function (that is provided thanks to the `'use strict';` statement at the top), and then use the position property of the actual object to check if it has already an array inside the targetObject, if not, I create a new array and push the player in to it.

The log statement at the end then shows you the output. I added the mapping from position QB to QuarterBack as an extra. If the map isn't found, it would take the actual position :)

```js
'use strict';

var arrayOfObject = [
    { name: 'player', position: 'QB' },
    { name: 'player 2', position: 'W' },
    { name: 'player 3', position: 'RW' }
], targetObject = {}, map = {
  'QB': 'QuarterBacks',
  'W': 'Wingers',
  'RW': 'RightWingers'
};


arrayOfObject.forEach(function(player) {
  var pos = player.position,
      mappedPosition = map[pos] || pos;
  if (!targetObject[mappedPosition]) {
    targetObject[mappedPosition] = [];
  }
  targetObject[mappedPosition].push(player);
});

console.log(targetObject);
```

Comment: sorry @Icepickle, little green at this stuff so I'm not totally sure how the targetObject and map work — since those aren't included within my current Roster object (or in your example, the arrayOfObject). 

not really sure how to apply this solution to my code at the top :/ sorry! could you explain a bit further? thanks for the help!

Comment: actually just got it to work in my code, but it returned an object with no players in it.

Answer (score 0):

I might do this slightly differently, but JavaScript seems to allow you to do things in a plethora of ways. If I cannibalize the list from the answer from @dspano, I get this for my code:

```
function createListByPosition(inputList, desiredPosition) {
    var outputList = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
        var position = inputList[i].position;
        if (position === desiredPosition)
        {
            outputList.push(inputList[i])
        }
    }
    return outputList;
}
var quaterbackList = createListByPosition(roster, 'qb');
```

This also has the benefit of being pretty generic.